# System.ObjectDisposedException: "Cannot access a closed file." после ожидания отправки потока

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-web-services

Ребят, такая проблема. Есть метод для отправки картинок в хранилище.

```
string path = "images/";
bucketName = "myBucketName";

public void UploadImage(IFormFile formFile, string name)
{
    var request = new PutObjectRequest()
    {
        Key = $"{path}{name}",
        InputStream = formFile.OpenReadStream(),
        BucketName = bucketName,
    };

    request.Metadata.Add("Content-Type", formFile.ContentType);

    client.PutObjectAsync(request);
}
```

Вызываю его в тестовом консольном приложении, все работает, картинка отправляется на сервер. Но если вызываю его в asp.net проекте в Post методе.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Edit(ServiceItem model, IFormFile titleImageFile)
{
    if(Model.IsValid)
    {
        if (titleImageFile != null)
        {
            dataManager.ImageHandler.UploadImage(titleImageFile, model.Id.ToString());
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(HomeController.Index), nameof(HomeController).CutController());
        }

        dataManager.ServiceItems.SaveServiceItem(model);
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(HomeController.Index), nameof(HomeController).CutController());
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

Выбрасывает исключение `System.ObjectDisposedException: "Cannot access a closed file."`.
В Startup есть связанный с ним код.

```
services.AddTransient<IImageHandlerRepository>(x =>
{
    return new AWSImageRepository(new AmazonS3Client(Config.AWSAccesToken, Config.AWSSecretAccesToken, new AmazonS3Config()
    {
        ForcePathStyle = true,
        RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.EUWest1,
        ServiceURL = Config.ServiceURL
    }), Config.BucketName);
});
```

Как исправить эту ошибку? Буду благодарен любой помощи.

Comment: [Метод AddTransient() создает transient-объекты. Такие объекты создаются при каждом обращении к ним.](https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/6.2.php)

Comment: Сменил на Singleton, та же проблема.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Асинхронность, `client.PutObjectAsync` вызван неверно

```
public Task UploadImageAsync(IFormFile formFile, string name)
{
    var request = new PutObjectRequest()
    {
        Key = $"{path}{name}",
        InputStream = formFile.OpenReadStream(),
        BucketName = bucketName,
    };

    request.Metadata.Add("Content-Type", formFile.ContentType);

    return client.PutObjectAsync(request);
}
```

```
await dataManager.ImageHandler.UploadImageAsync(titleImageFile, model.Id.ToString());
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! А почему в моем примере выше это не сработало?

Comment: @CSEON что не сработало? Метод контроллера завершался раньше, чем загрузка картинки, потому что вы не ожидали завершения `PutObjectAsync`